# PHP - Sort alphabetically and assign values to specific variables

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp-3.0

PHP beginner here. Looking for a more efficient code.

I have a model, named `Brands` and I am trying to extract, sort and display the values alphabetically in my view.

For example:

**Brands' name starting from the alphabet A**

1. Brand1
2. Brand2
   .....etc.

**Brands' name starting from the alphabet K**

1. Brand1
2. Brand2
   .....etc.

I am able to do the same by the following code:

$brandsTable = TableRegistry::get('Brands');

```
    $brandA = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'A%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'a%');

    $brandK = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'K%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'k%');

    $brandS = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'S%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 's%');

    $brandT = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'T%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 't%');

    $brandN = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'N%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'n%');

    $brandH = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'H%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'h%');

    $brandM = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'M%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'm%');

    $brandY = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'Y%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'y%');

    $brandR = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'R%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'r%');

    $brandW = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
        'deleted =' => 0
        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'W%'
        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
        ])->bind(':key', 'w%');

    $this->set('brandsA', $brandA);
    $this->set('brandsK', $brandK);
    $this->set('brandsS', $brandS);
    $this->set('brandsT', $brandT);
    $this->set('brandsN', $brandN);
    $this->set('brandsH', $brandH);
    $this->set('brandsM', $brandM);
    $this->set('brandsY', $brandY);
    $this->set('brandsR', $brandR);
    $this->set('brandsW', $brandW);
```

I believe it is **not** the most efficient way to call the model / execute query so many times. Tried looking for efficient solution (Hash:extract / sort, etc.) But unable to get a proper output. Would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Note: deleted flag is for logical delete.

**Update:**
After ThinTank and ndm comment
Sorry for not mentioning that, As it is a Japanese website I am looking for case sensitive brands' name starting from

[ A,E,I,O,U ],[ K ],[ S ],[ T ],[ N ],[ H ],[ M ],[ Y ],[ R ],[ W ]

respectively.Example : I have brands as follows

adidas, Allison, Edox, Reebok, Tissot, etc.

**Output should be:**
Brands' name starting from ア [A,E,I,O,U]:
adidas
Allison
Edox

Brands' name starting from ラ [R]:
Reebok

Brands' name starting from タ [T]:
Tissot
... and so on,

Comment: Do you want all the brands ? Or only this concerns by the letters 'A', 'K', 'S', 'T', 'N', 'H', 'M', 'Y', 'R', 'W' ?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what exactly you are trying to do, for example by adding an example of the data in your database, the final data that you are looking for, and the actual conditions that are required to retrieve it. Also since you are somehow trying to take case sensitivity into account, you should make clear if that is really required, ie whether your database/table/column is actually using a case sensitive collation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to factorize it :

```
$listBrandsLetter = array('A', 'K', 'S', 'T', 'N', 'H', 'M', 'Y', 'R', 'W');

$brandsTable = TableRegistry::get('Brands');

foreach($listBrandsLetter as $letter)
{
    $currentBrand = $brandsTable->find('all')->where([
                        'deleted =' => 0
                        ])-> andWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
                        ])->bind(':key', $letter.'%'
                        )-> orWhere(['brand_name_eng LIKE :key'
                        ])->bind(':key', strtolower($letter).'%');

    $this->set('brands'.$letter, $currentBrand);
}
```

If your objective is to reduce the number of query due to performance issues, thanks to notify it.
If performance is okay, just factoring should be enough

Comment: `$listBrandsLetter` may be obtained from the database, too, like this: `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(brand_name_eng,1,1) FROM ...`